# C++ pushing back a string by value in a vector

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector

I'm doing some algorithmics problem and I'm having trouble with managing functions, vectors and strings in C++.

I have to find a concrete path in a matrix and for that, I need to have all the different paths, so I decided to use a function. This function will check where to continue to search. Here is the code of the function:

```
vector<string> get_all_paths(string actual, int rows, int columns, int col_actual, int row_prev) {
    vector<string> solutions;
    int row_actual = (rows+row_prev-1)%rows;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        cout << col_actual << " " << row_actual << "\n";
        //cout << (dp[row_prev][col_actual+1] - matrix[row_prev][col_actual+1]) << " " << dp[row_actual][col_actual] << "\n";
        if( (dp[row_prev][col_actual+1] - matrix[row_prev][col_actual+1]) == dp[row_actual][col_actual] ) {

            if (col_actual > 0) {

                //cout << "--" << actual << " " << row_actual << "\n";
                string branch = actual + to_string(row_actual+1) + " ";
                solutions = get_best_path(branch, rows, columns, col_actual-1, row_actual);
                //cout << ".." << actual << "\n"; 

            } else {

                //cout << actual << " " << row_actual << "\n";
                cout << actual << "\n";
                string branch = actual.c_str();
                branch += to_string(row_actual+1);
                cout << branch << "\n";
                solutions.push_back( branch );
                break;

            }

        }
        row_actual = (row_actual+1)%rows;

    }
    for(auto i : solutions) cout << "--" << i << "\n";

    return solutions;

}
```

And here is the call to the method:

```
vector<string> solutions;
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

    if (dp[i][cols-1] == min_path) {

        cout << "................\n";
        solutions = get_best_path( (to_string(i+1)+" "), rows, cols, cols-2, i);
        for(auto i : solutions) {
            reverse(i.begin(), i.end());
            cout << i << "\n";
        }
        cout << "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n";

    }

}
```

The thing is that I'm getting three paths for a given example, which is correct, but they are all the same string, which is the last path or the last change done in variable *branch*.

Maybe I'm mixing a lot of concepts and maybe this has been answered a lot of times, but I've searched this and got nothing.

EDIT: I'm not getting three paths from the function, just the last one, but when printing inside the function the paths i do have three inside that function all with the same value, sorry about that.

EDIT2: The idea of the problem is to find the minimum cost path in a given matrix and, if there are more than 1, the one that is the smallest lexicographically. So given a matrix:

5 4

9 1 9 9

1 9 9 9

9 9 9 9

1 1 1 1

9 9 1 9

My approach is to use dp as a matrix with the dynamic programming results and then i try to recreate all the paths in the function above.

In this case, the dp matrix is:

9 2 11 12

1 10 11 20

9 10 11 12

1 2 3 4

9 10 3 12

And so, the best paths are:

4 4 4 4

4 5 4 4

2 1 5 4

And the one correct is the last one.

Inside my function i do get the different paths and i add them to the vector of results, but then i lose them when searching for more.

Thanks for the time if you have read this :D!

Comment: Completely unrelated to your problem, but what is this `string branch = actual.c_str();`? Just do this `string branch = actual;`

Comment: add `&` to reverse: `for(auto& i : solutions) { reverse(i.begin(), i.end()); ... }`

Comment: @john I already did that, but i thought that maybe c_str() was giving the value of the string and the direct assignation was giving a reference, but it also didn't work.

Comment: @user3365922 that didn't work, but thanks to your comment i noticed that the vector only gets 1 string in the end.

Comment: @Chechu I expect you have a logic error in your code somewhere, unfortunately there's not enough information in the question to tell what that is. At the very least you should add the input you are working with and the output you see. Don't try and describe things, **show** them.

Comment: A function called `get_best_path()` should return a single path. Perhaps `get_best_paths()`? Also "best" is very vague. Your parameter names are not easy to figure out either. Finally, `std::string`s are not a very useful structure to keep your partial paths in.

Comment: @john I added more information, thank you for the tip.

Comment: @einpoklum Thanks for the tips and I'm sorry about the code being difficult to read. In that case, which structure should I use to keep the parcial paths?

Comment: @Chechu: "When in doubt, use an `std::vector`..." <- Words of wisdom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I *think* the problem is here

```
solutions = get_best_path(branch, rows, columns, col_actual-1, row_actual);
```

because that assignment replaces any solutions you might have found so far. Instead you should append any solutions returned to any that you've found so far. In other words something like this

```
vector<string> tmp = get_best_path(branch, rows, columns, col_actual-1, row_actual);
solutions.insert(solutions.end(), tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
```

But this is just intuition, I haven't tested anything.